# How can I pass a type, rather than an instance, to a function in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types

I am attempting to use reflection to enumerate class fields and methods in order to do some automation in a web application. I am also abstracting this so that I could pass in any class.

Is there a way I could somehow pass in the type directly to a function to enumerate on rather than an instance of the type?

I would like the caller side to look like this:

```
var m = new MyClass(AClassOfSomeTypeIDefined);
```

I would like to avoid creating an instance as that is misleading to anyone who might use the class (as the instance isn't directly used).

Comment: In addition to the answers given you could also look for generics at msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System;

public void UseType(Type t) {
    // do something with t using reflection techniques - e.g.
    Console.WriteLine("compat with int? {0}", typeof(int).IsAssignableFrom(t));
}
```

Call it with C# [`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) keyword and the data type you want to pass.

```
// Examples...
UseType( typeof(int) );
UseType( typeof(System.Int32) );
UseType( typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Button) );
UseType( typeof(IDisposable) );
UseType( typeof(WhateverTypeYouWant) );
```

`System.Type` is one of the cornerstones of reflection as you already know, so run with it.

---

**Other notes**
Depending on what you want to do with the type, the following peripheral details might be useful.

To create an instance of a `Type` at runtime without having used the `new` keyword at compile time, use the [`System.Activator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx) class. e.g.

```
// Create a List of strings like: new List<string>();
var list = (List<string>) Activator.CreateInstance( typeof(List<string>) );
```

Answer (score 1):

yes just use the [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) of your class. There's two basic ways to get the type:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Type myType = foo.GetType();
Type myTyp2 = typeof(Foo);
```

You can use `GetType()` if you only know the type at runtime (more common with reflection), or `typeof()` if you know the type at compile time already.

In your example this would be i.e.

```
var m = new MyClass(typeof(Foo));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `Type` object just like any other parameter.

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(Type yourType)
    {
        // do as you please with yourType
    }
}
```

The call it:

```
var m = new MyClass(typeof(YourType));
```